# Firebase onAuthStateChanged is being called twice upon login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase. I'm trying to login using React + Redux. When I click 'Login', it will log me in once, then the onAuthStateChanged is called again with `res` being null which logs me back out

Here's my Firebase service:

```
const initFirebase = () => {

    firebase.initializeApp(config.firebase)

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((res) => {
        console.log('Firebase - onAuthStateChanged', {res})

        if(res) {
            const formData = {
                email: res.email,
                uid: res.uid,
            }

            // Check if email exists against local API
            APIAuthService(endpoint, 'post', formData).then(response => {
                if(response.status) {
                    let userData = response.data
                    store.dispatch(authAction.login(userData))
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            store.dispatch(authAction.logout())
        }
    })
}
```

Also my Login.js component can viewed here (Line:41) https://pastebin.com/qcRH6gv2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is normal, onAuthStateChanged will keep triggering. You can prevent from multiple calls with this code:

```
var authFlag = true;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((res) => {
    if(res && authFlag) {
        console.log('Firebase - onAuthStateChanged', {res})
        authFlag = false;
        //rest of your code
```

Comment: Do I need to set authFlag true on my login component?

Comment: Just inside `const initFirebase `

Comment: I'm a little confused, would that still work when users click logout? I guess it would make sense to set authFlag to true once they've logged out, right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to make another call just set authFlag to true :)

Comment: No it's NOT normal. It can't just trigger when the state doesn't change. The name says onAuthStateChanged implies it. It's the mis-implementation or mis-naming. If we don't understand the underlying mechanism, and just skip the first time, there's a risk of NOT running the code below.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap it inside useEffect.
Works for me

```
useEffect(()=> {
   onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
   ....
   }
}, [])
```

Comment: Of course you must wrap it in useEffect to register once. But no matter where you put, the listener is triggered twice. It's firebase's issue.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a way to simply listen to the state changed only once then just assign the `onAuthStateChanged` to a variable, that will be the unsubscribed function and simply call it. So for example something like this:

```
const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  unsubscribe();
  // Do something with the user...
  console.log('firebase user:', user);
});
```